# How do protons and electrons separate across a conductor in the Hall Effect, if protons "don't move"?

Tags: electricity, charge, hall-effect

I have a (probably *very*) basic understanding of electricity, how/why current flows, etc. from my ham technician's license. I often think of the water-in-a-hose analogy, how pressure (voltage?) causes water to flow (current?). However, I'm confused on what actually flows in a wire. I'm pretty sure that the current flowing is actually only electrons "jumping" across atoms continuously through the wire (in a DC circuit, anyways). Here's where my confusion is.

In the diagram below, it shows that when a magnet is placed near a basic Hall Effect sensor, it causes protons and electrons to separate across the diagonal axis to the current flowing, creating a voltage. However, I've also heard that protons don't actually move. Am I correct in assuming that the *electrons* are indeed "pushed"/"pulled" to the side, but the showing the protons is just a simplified way of showing that there is an imbalance of the proton-to-electron ratio, creating a "void" of the lack of electrons, and it is *this* that causes the voltage?

[image]

Sorry if this isn't worded well, feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: Please include the diagram in your question post.

Comment: Oops, i forgot to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you got it exactly right! If en electron from one side moves to the other side, it leaves behind a positive "hole" and this is where the positive charge there comes from.